# C# DatagridView change the text entered in a cell during validation

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have a datagridView with a cell whose data type is Datetime.
The value of the cell is formatted as HH:mm (hours, minutes).
When the user edits the cell with a value like 5, I would like to transform it into 05:00 before the datagridView complains that the value entered is not a valid datetime.

I have tried the validating event but there I cannot change the Formatted value, I can only Cancel.
I know what I am asking is possible because I have done it in another project, but I cannot access the code of that project to see how I did it.
Please help. Thanks

Comment: You can change the Value, can't you`? The FormattedValue is created by the system.

Comment: Hi, in which event do I change the value?

Comment: Right in `CellValidating` with appropriate checks, of course.

Comment: But if even if I change the value in cellValidating, the datagridview will still complain that the value entered by the user is wrong

Comment: Hm, did you set `e.Cancel = false;` ? Are there other validations?

Comment: At the moment I have nothing in the cellvalidating event. I can only set e.Cancel = true there, If I do not, the Grid will popup an error that the data entered is not a valid datetime.

Comment: Well if the column needs `DateTime` then you must set the `Value` to a valid `DateTime`, of course.Neither `5` nor `05:00`.

Comment: The system recognizes 5:00 when it is entered because that is the format of time. So it uses the Datetime value and changes only the part of the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem using the CellParsing event. There I get the Value entered from the user and I can parse it into a proper datetime and finally set e.ParsingApplied = true (very important otherwise the parsing you did is ignored)